# alert(); not working with jquery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

alert function is not working with rest of the code (working using bootstrap,jquery,js) ,it works if i remove everything else below it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
      var c=3;
      var a="user";
      var b="123";

      $("#b1").on('click', function () {
         alert("Hi");
          while((c!=0)&&($("#user").text())=a)
              {

              if($("#pwd").text()=b)
                  {
                      $("#modal").text("Log In Successful") ;
                  }
              else{
                 $("#modal").text("Sign in failed, try again,"+c+" chances left") ;
                  c--;
              }
              }

      });


  </script>
```

If i write the alert in this fashion , it works

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
      var c=3;
      var a="user";
      var b="123";
      $("#b1").on('click', function () {
         alert("Hi");
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: also - just one thing - make sure that you are wrapping the jQuery stuff in a $(document).ready({}) wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is this line:

```
while((c!=0)&&($("#user").text())=a)
```

you are not using the comparison operator.

change it to

```
while((c!=0)&&($("#user").text()) == a)
```

same with your if statement

```
if($("#pwd").text()=b)
```

change it to

```
if($("#pwd").text() == b)
```

and see if that works

Answer (score 2):

You are using `=` operator in your `while` loop as well as in your `if` statement, which makes the condition inside always true. Use the `==` operator instead.

```
while((c!=0)&&($("#user").text())==a){
  if($("#pwd").text()==b){
     $("#modal").text("Log In Successful") ;
  }
  else{
     $("#modal").text("Sign in failed, try again,"+c+" chances left") ;
     c--;
  }
}
```

Comment: ha ha kittyCat - i just posted that - got in just before you :) ... its a race with these answers :)

Comment: but you forgot the if statement.

Comment: yup - got that in there now .